# Presto SQL to find number of transactions in the year before the current transaction

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a (simplified) transaction table of customer and order date. For each row/order I want to find the number of orders the year before the current order. I can do this with a self join, but when my transactions table is far bigger, it gets inefficient. I think I really want to use a window function with range between on the date field, but this isn't implemented in Presto yet. Any ideas of how I can do this more efficiently?

```
   with
    transactions as (
        select
            1 as customer,
            date '2020-01-01' as order_date
        union all
        select
            1 as customer,
            date '2020-01-26' as order_date
        union all
        select
            1 as customer,
            date '2020-02-01' as order_date
        union all
        select
            1 as customer,
            date '2020-02-02' as order_date
    )
select
    t1.*,
    count(case when t2.order_date between date_add('day', -14, t1.order_date) and date_add('day', -1, t1.order_date) then t2.order_date else null end) as orders_14_days_before
from
    transactions t1
    left join
        transactions t2 on t1.customer = t2.customer
group by
    t1.customer,
    t1.order_date
```

Result:

```
customer    order_date  orders_14_days_before
1   2020-01-01  0
1   2020-01-26  0
1   2020-02-01  1
1   2020-02-02  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto does not seem to fully support the `range` window specification.  So you can do this another way . . . by doings ins-and-outs:

```
with cd as (
      select customer, order_date as dte, 1 as inc
      from transactions
      union all
      select customer, order_date + interval '1' year, -1 inc
      from transactions
     )
select t.*, cd.one_year_count
from (select customer, dte,
               sum(sum(inc)) over (partition by customer order by dte) as one_year_count
      from cd
      group by customer, date
     ) cd join
     transactions t
     on cd.dte = t.order_date;
```

You should find that this is much faster.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Athena (Presto 0.217). I get:

`SYNTAX_ERROR: line 27:14: 'customer' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause`.  
I haven't seen this `sum(sum()) over ...` before - is it called something specifically? Trying to see if it is supported by Athena

Comment: Actually I've managed to get it working. Will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gordon Linoff's answer above, I tweaked it to get the correct answer (at least in Athena). You don't need the `sum(sum()) over ...`, just `sum() over ...` is sufficient.

```
with
    transactions as (
        select
            1 as customer,
            date '2020-01-01' as order_date
        union all
        select
            1 as customer,
            date '2020-01-26' as order_date
        union all
        select
            1 as customer,
            date '2020-02-01' as order_date
        union all
        select
            1 as customer,
            date '2020-02-02' as order_date
    ),
    cd as (
        select
            customer,
            order_date as dte,
            1 as inc
        from
            transactions
        union all
        select
            customer,
            order_date + interval '13' day,
            -1 inc
        from
            transactions
    ),
    cd2 as (
        select
            customer,
            dte,
            inc,
            sum(inc) over (partition by customer order by dte rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as one_year_count
        from
            cd
    )
select
    t.*,
    coalesce(cd2.one_year_count, 0) as one_year_count
from
    cd2
    inner join
        transactions t
        on cd2.dte = t.order_date
where
    cd2.inc = 1
order by
    2 asc
```